# How to create a Constraint for 2 columns mysql

Tags: mysql

I have have created a database with 3 tables:
Products
Categories
Subcategories

In my products table I have a category and a subcategory column:

```
| product_name | category | subcategory|  
----------------------------------------    
| varchar      | int      | int        |
```

As of right now the category column references the categories table id and the subcategory column references the subcategories id.

The categories column has an id and a category name column:

```
| id | category_name |
----------------------
|int | varchar       |
```

The subcategories column has an id, sub category and a parent column which is a  foreign key that references the categories(id) column.

```
| id | subcategory_name | parent |
---------------------------------
|int | varchar          | int    |
```

I wanted to know if there is a way to add a constraint to the products's 'subcategories' column so that one would only be able to add a value if it was a legitimate child of the parent category.

Forgive me if this question has been answered already. I do not know the proper name for what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

1 - you can use program to verify before insert / update the sub-cat id

2 - or you can use a trigger to run after each transaction

3 - or you can redesign your category and sub-category table, it depends on how your category data look.

eg:

```
id   category_name
---- -------------
10   cat 10
1011 kid of cat 10
20   cat 20
2020 kid of cat 20
```

4 - If you do not like above design, you can also design this way:

```
id   category      parent_id
---- ------------- -----
10   cat 10         0
1010 kid of cat 10  10
20   cat 20         0
2020 kid of cat 20  20
```

Comment: From what I understand, my design is similar to your second option. I wanted to know if there was a way to enforce the foreign key restrictions on the subcategories column of my products table.    

eg.  if a foreign key id is inserted in the subcategory field of the products table that is not a child of the entered category field then the entry would be invalid.

Comment: would the MySQL docs help you? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html